# Is there a standard action that inserts text, that can be used in a key binding?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am fairly new to eclipse as far as it regards programming. After reading docs and faqs the whole day, I learned that key sequences can be bound to commands, which in turn can invoke actions (or was it the other way around?). Anyway, I miss a list of "standard actions", surely, inserting a character in response to a key stroke must be standard? But I din't find it.

In an editor I want to bind key sequences to actions like "insert character x", where x is one of a set of characters not on every keyboard (like §°€µöß´, greek letters, etc.).

How do I do this in eclipse?

Do I really have to write a separate command (and or action?) for every character I need? Moreover, if possible I want it to have configurable, of course. But, first things first.

In conventional editors like UltraEdit or jEdit, I would record a macro and bind a key sequence that invokes that. It's done in 1 minute. In jEdit, such a macro results in one line of bsh code that looks like:

```
insertText("§");
```

Comment: You can write a command which accepts a string parameter, and inserts it in the active editor (don't know if such a command exists already). You can also create keybindings to call a command with a given parameter in `plugin.xml`: see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Command_Framework#Executing_a_command_with_parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the Eclipse plugin [Practically Macro](https://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/). It allows you to record macros but also to define it by hand.

To create a short key that inserts "§" in your editor you must do the following steps:

1. Go into "Preferences/Practically Macro Options/Editor Macro Definitions" and create a new macro. Add the command "Insert String" and type § in the text field. Then give the macro a name and an id, e.g., "testmacro".
2. Go to "Preferences/General/Keys" and search for your newly created "testmacro". You can now bind an arbitrary key combination to it.

Comment: Thank you for help. A macro facility was just what I missed.