# Eclipse - always add "//" when i hit ctrl /

Tags: eclipse

When I'm in eclipse, whenever i'm editing any sort of file - be it .html or .java or .pokemon, I would like ctrl-/ to always put two // at the beginning of whatever line i'm on.

How do I tell eclipse to do this?

*This is absolutely not a duplicate. I have no idea how you could think it is a duplicate, the answer given to it is about recording macros for goodness' sake.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a standard action that inserts text, that can be used in a key binding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229044/is-there-a-standard-action-that-inserts-text-that-can-be-used-in-a-key-binding)

Comment: @JonSampson i don't think you're right, nor that the selected answer is viable here.